# Same node code with python child process does not work in another operating system and hardware

Tags: python, node.js, virtual-machine, gpu

We were developing a web page that utilizes node.js server, webpack and python child process altogether. A request is being sent to python child process and after the python child process has been successfully finalized all the results have been displayed using node.js server.

After the development phase, we have decided to move the system to another machine having better specs. However, when we have moved and initiated the system we have seen that only a single child process is being run in the system. In the development machine, the node was allowing the python code to run on multiple processors and threads. However, in the development machine, only one is allowed and it is working on CPU. I am very new to the Node concept however what we have seen throughout the tests and different virtual machines we could not find any solution nor any explanation for this situation to happen.

Development Machine Specs:
- RAM: 12 GB
- display : GF108M [GeForce GT 540M]
- Operating System: Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS 
- CPU(s) : 8
- CPU model : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2670QM CPU @ 2.20GHz
- Architecture: x86_64

Deployment Machine Specs:
- RAM: 32 GB
- display : NVIDIA Quatro M400
- Operating System: Windows 10 Pro
- CPU(s) : 32
- CPU model : Intel(R) Xeon(R) E7 v3/Xeon(R) E5 v3/Core i7 Buffered Ring Agent- 2FF8
- Architecture: x86_64

We have tried to use different virtual machines and operating system however always the same result. I think we are missing some part to enable node or python to utilize GPU in the child process.

All the necessary modules to initiate the system is as follows,
a most important one for the system is pyhseds which I assume that it utilizes numpy, rasterio in the background

```py
import os
import sys
import json
from geojson import Polygon
import numpy as np
from pysheds.grid import Grid
from pyproj import Proj, transform
import tarfile
```

Since the system is being carried out in only one single process the calculation time increases tremendously. 
In the development machine, the same process takes only half a second whereas in the deployment machine it increases 10 - 30 seconds. In some cases, it does not return any value at all.

Comment: Can you run the python program by itself and benchmark it alone on the two systems?  It would be nice to first determine whether this is only a performance issue with your python program and something that has nothing to do with node.js or not.

Answer (score 0):

After going through the code we have find the reason that causing this problem. We observed that the `pyproj` library version newer than  `1.9.6` does not fully allow code to run as expected. After downgrading from `2.2.1`  to   `1.9.6` the code yields results ten times faster. I really do not know the reason or should we apply further palatalization or threading while using `pyproj` libraries in the newer versions but for the time being it seems we have overcome our performance problem.

```py
import pyproj
```